# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_JanComponent])[UpdateDataModel->UpdateDataModel->UpdateDataModel->UpdateDataModel]:NullInjectorError

Tags: angular17

I am working on a project that requires me to create a form and submit data from it using a web API. However, when I try to do that, I get a NullInjector error.

**angular version:** **angular 17**

**app.config.ts**

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient()
]};
```

**jan.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UpdateDataService } from '../Services/update-data.service';
import { UpdateDataModel } from '../Model/update-dataModel';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-jan',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,ReactiveFormsModule,HttpClientModule],
  templateUrl: './jan.component.html',
  styleUrl: './jan.component.css'
})

export class JanComponent  {
  Form: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private updateDataService:UpdateDataService,
    private ModelObj : UpdateDataModel) {
    this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id:[''],
      name: [''],
      mobileNo: [''],
      email: [''],
      address: ['']
    }); 
  }

  submit(Form: any){
    this.ModelObj.Id = Form.control["id"].Values;
    this.ModelObj.Name = Form.control["name"].Values;
    this.ModelObj.MobileNo = Form.control["mobileNo"].Values;
    this.ModelObj.Email = Form.control["email"].Values;
    this.ModelObj.Address = Form.control["address"].Values;
    this.updateDataService.UpdateData(this.ModelObj).subscribe((response: any)=>{
      console.log('Data updated successfully:', response);

    });
  }
}
```

update-data.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UpdateDataModel } from '../Model/update-dataModel';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UpdateDataService {


  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:12757/Api/updateData';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  UpdateData(updateData: UpdateDataModel):any{
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl,updateData)
  }
}
```

I have tried to follow the instructions, but I still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.